# problem with bootMer CI: upper and lower limits are identical

Tags: lme4

I'm having the hardest time generating confidence intervals for my glmer poisson model. After following several very helpful tutorials (such as https://drewtyre.rbind.io/classes/nres803/week_12/lab_12/) as well as stackoverflow posts, I keep getting very strange results, i.e. the upper and lower limits of the CI are identical.

Here is a reproducible example containing a response variable called "production," a fixed effect called "Treatment_Num" and a random effect called "Genotype":

```
df1 <- data.frame(production=c(15,12,10,9,6,8,9,5,3,3,2,1,0,0,0,0), Treatment_Num=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4), Genotype=c(1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2))
```

#run the glmer model

```
df1_glmer <- glmer(production ~ Treatment_Num +(1|Genotype),
                     data = df1, family = poisson(link = "log"))
```

#make an empty data set to predict from, that contains the explanatory variables but no response

```
require(magrittr)
df_empty <- df1 %>%
  tidyr::expand(Treatment_Num, Genotype)
```

#create new column containing predictions

```
df_empty$PopPred <- predict(df1_glmer, newdata = df_empty, type="response",re.form = ~0)
```

#function for bootMer

```
myFunc_df1_glmer <- function(mm) {
  predict(df1_glmer, newdata = df_empty, type="response",re.form=~0)
}
```

#run bootMer

```
require(lme4)
    merBoot_df1_glmer <- bootMer(df1_glmer, myFunc_df1_glmer, nsim = 10)
```

#get confidence intervals out of it

```
predCL <- t(apply(merBoot_df1_glmer$t, MARGIN = 2, FUN = quantile, probs = c(0.025, 0.975)))
```

#enter lower and upper limits of confidence interval into df_empty

```
df_empty$lci <- predCL[, 1]
df_empty$uci <- predCL[, 2]
```

#when viewing df_empty the problem becomes clear: the lci and uci are identical!

```
df_empty
```

[image: df_empty]

Any insights you can give me will be much appreciated!

Comment: Hi Carrie -- thanks for the advertising! When you run your actual dataset do you get the message `boundary (singular) fit: see ?isSingular`? I don't know if that's part of the problem or not, just checking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignore my comment!

The issue is with the function you created to pass to `bootMer()`. You wrote:

```
myFunc_df1_glmer <- function(mm) {
  predict(df1_glmer, newdata = df_empty, type="response",re.form=~0)
}
```

The argument `mm` should be a fitted model object derived from the bootstrapped data.
However, you don't pass this object to `predict()`, but rather the original model
object. If you change the function to:

```
myFunc_df1_glmer <- function(mm) {
  predict(mm, newdata = df_empty, type="response",re.form=~0)
         #^^ pass in the object created by bootMer 
}
```

then it works:

```
> df_empty

# A tibble: 8 x 5

  Treatment_Num Genotype PopPred   lci   uci
          <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1             1        1  12.9   9.63  15.7 
2             1        2  12.9   9.63  15.7 
3             2        1   5.09  3.87   5.89
4             2        2   5.09  3.87   5.89
5             3        1   2.01  1.20   2.46
6             3        2   2.01  1.20   2.46
7             4        1   0.796 0.361  1.14
8             4        2   0.796 0.361  1.14
```

As an aside -- how many genotypes in your actual data? If less than 5-7 you might
do better using a straight up `glm()` with genotype as a factor using sum-to-zero
contrasts.